# What type of wood is the rarest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make an All Blox Shop, so that means getting every block, including wood. So I have to figure out exactly how rare the wood is, so I can make a fair price.

How rare are the types of wood depending on forest rarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SF commented, all trees can be farmed, so once you have found at least one of each, it shouldn't matter it's *rarity*, but rather, how easily you can replant them. I didn't find anything about their rarity in [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree), anyway. It might be possible to check the list of every biome in which they can generate, and check the rarity of those biomes instead. But it won't matter anyway once you have a few saplings of each type.

Regarding the difficulty to farm them, I'd argue that the hardest one is, by far, the dark oak.

Oak, spruce, birch, jungle and acacia can be grown with just one sapling. And unless you decide to collect all the leaves with silk touch, you're almost guaranteed to get several saplings back from each chopped tree. So, they're self-sustained farms.

Dark oak, on the other hand, is the only tree that can *only* be grown with 2x2 saplings. Spruce and jungle also have that *option*, but it's a choice: 1 sapling for a regular tree, or 2x2 for a humongous, giant one. With dark oak, it's either 2x2 or nothing.

Also, from personal experience (in Bedrock edition), you don't get as many saplings back. If you break by hand every single leaf block, you get between 3 and 5 saplings back. Maybe 6 if you're lucky. But you invested 4 to grow the tree, so... it can still be self-sustained, but you have to be careful not to let any saplings despawn. Which could easily happen if you're cutting down a lot of trees at a time.

As SF pointed out, breaking the leaves with a [Fortune III](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortune#Tabulated_probabilities) hoe will increase the amount of saplings you get back (you get exactly twice as many), making it easier to keep growing trees. But it's still extra work that you don't really need to do with any other type of tree.

Comment: Fortune III hoe will produce plenty of saplings.

Comment: @SF true, 10% of the leaves will drop a sapling instead of just 5%, according to the wiki. For some reason I thought Fortune didn't apply to breaking leaves. I still think dark oak is more difficult, but less so than before.

Answer (score 1):

Most common to most rare:

- Oak
- Birch
- Spruce
- Dark Oak (May fail to be self-sustained)
- Acacia
- Jungle
- Warped/Crimson (requires bonemeal and nylium)

Comment: Can you add commas, or a bulleted list? Also, I was actually hoping for an answer with percentages. Whatever the case, you did good.

Comment: Warped and crimson _can_ be farmed. They just take red or blue fungus thingies instead of saplings, and nylium instead of regular grass or dirt

Comment: Warped/crimson can be farmed, it's just a 2-step process. Bonemeal Nylium for it to sprout the small crimson/warped shrooms, then bonemeal these shrooms. There are even fully self-sufficient farms of these, producing enough bonemeal from the nether wart blocks that they can break even bonemealing a piece of nylium until it sprouts a shroom, then bonemealing that shroom, all without player intervention.

Comment: @SF You could do it that way or you could just find a piece of warped/crimson fungus and bonemeal it.

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow I think you're missing the concept of 'farming'.